# Ubuntu Message Queue Makefile Error

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, message-queue

I have a problem with message queues in C in Ubuntu. I use VirtualBox to run the Ubuntu.

I took error which is "undefined reference to mq_open. ld returned 1 exit status".

I know there is a same question as this but I tried that solution but it did not worked, so I want to ask again. Please help!

Here is my code, it is really simple but I can not even compile it.

this is my deneme.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "sharedMsg.h"

int main()
{
  mqd_t mq;
  mq = mq_open(MQNAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
}
```

this is my sharedMsg.h

```
struct item{
  char *word;
  int lineNum;
};

#define MQNAME "/sentmsg"
```

and finally this is my MakeFile

```
all: deneme
deneme: deneme.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o deneme deneme.c -lrt
clean:
    rm -fr *~ *.o
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you have executed `sudo apt-get install build-essential` ? And your Makefile is broken. `all: `requires `deneme` but you provided `deneme1`!

Comment: yes I executed build -essential even to be sure again, I type this and install again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your Makefile is that your `all` target depends on `demene` but the target that specifies `-lrt` is called `demene1`. Thus, the default inference rules kick in and `demene` is attempted to be linked without `-lrt`. The rule for `deneme1` is also wrong in that it attempts to create a binary named `deneme`, even though the rule should create `deneme1`. To resolve this, change the first to third lines to

```
all: deneme1
deneme1: deneme.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o deneme1 deneme.c -lrt
```

or the second line to

```
deneme: deneme.c
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I changed the second line but it still give the same error

Comment: What did you type to build the program? Just `make`? Can you show me your corrected makefile?

Comment: yes I write just    "make deneme"  but it cannot compile it and I corrected my makefile in my question also

Comment: @IremHerguner Make sure the `gcc -g ...` line is prefixed with a tabulator, not spaces! Makefiles require you to use tabulators for indentation, spaces may not work.

Comment: We wants it, we needs it. Must have the precious. They stole it from us. Sneaky little @FUZxxl. Wicked, tricksy, false! (J.R.R. Tolkien).  ;)

Answer (score 1):

(Note: The OP has edited the question and fixed the Makefile after this answer)

You have a broken Makefile.
The reason why you've even seen the linker error is that you have probably executed `make deneme`. In that case `make` will try to compile `dename.c` with default compiler options (because it did not find a target called `deneme`) and the default options do not include `-lrt`.

You have to fix your Makefile (replace `deneme1:` with `deneme:`)

```
all: deneme

deneme: deneme.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o deneme deneme.c -lrt

clean:
    rm -f deneme *~ *.o
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I changed the second line to "deneme" but it still give the same error

Comment: Does it compile if you manually execute `gcc deneme.c -o deneame -lrt`  ?

Comment: yesss ! , it compiles and even run but how could this be possible ? how can I fix my makefile than ?

Comment: You must have an error in your Makefile. Maybe you used spaces instead of tabs. Note that the tab character is a very important part of the syntax of Makefiles. All command lines must start with tabs.

Comment: You can try this Makefile in order to be sure: http://pastebin.com/raw/DwAzfWSd/Makefile

Comment: @FUZxxl  I wrote the file with tabs again but I still could not compile it with makefile, I can only compile it with manually command. Really thanks again

Comment: I copied and pasted your sent to my makefile, unfortunately nothing change, I can only compile it with manually

Comment: Maybe it is your editor. Try to download it unmodified.  In your source directory execute `rm Makefile; wget http://pastebin.com/raw/DwAzfWSd/Makefile`

Comment: wouvvv  I download it and it works now, as you said the editor is problem than. Thank you very very much really thanks.